# Finding joint distribution function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $U$ and $V$ be two independent uniform $(0,1)$ random variables and let
\begin{eqnarray*}
R &=&\sqrt{\frac{U^{2}+V^{2}}{2}},\\
H &=&\frac{2U}{U+V}.
\end{eqnarray*}
I found the marginal cumulative distribution function (cdf) of $R$ and $H$. The cumulative distribution functions (cdf) of $R$ and $H$ are given by
\begin{equation}
 F_{R}(t)=\left\{
\begin{array}{llll}
0,&~~  \mbox{ $t<0$},\\
\frac{\pi t^2}{2}, &~~  \mbox{ $0\leq t<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$},\\
t^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\arccos(\frac{1}{t\sqrt{2}})\right)+\sqrt{2t^2-1}, & ~~ \mbox{ $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\leq t< 1$},\\
1,&~~  \mbox{ $t\geq 1$},\\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation} F_{H}(t)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
0,&~~  \mbox{ $t<0$},\\
t+\frac{t^2}{2}\ln(\frac{2-t}{t}), &~~  \mbox{ $0\leq t<1$},\\
1,&~~  \mbox{ $t\geq 1$},\\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
respectively.
I want to find the joint cdf of $R$ and $H$, i.e.,
$$F_{R,H}(r,h)= Pr(R‎\leq r, H\leq h).$$

Comment: I allowed myself to remove the "distribution-theory" tag. Note that this tag is for questions about distributions as functionals on a space of test-functions (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) and not about probability distributions.

Comment: Semantics shmenantics. He starts with a pdf, and is looking for a pdf.